# Make fill-paragraph in python-mode work on paragraph, not whole string

Tags: python, fill-paragraph

If I have the following file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
bla.py

Does this and
that_
'''
```

..and call `fill-paragraph` with the cusor at `_`, then it acts on the entire docstring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''bla.py

Does this and that_

'''
```

rather than just the second paragraph.

Is there a way to make it act on just the current paragraph, so that the result is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
bla.py

Does this and that_    
'''
```

(I know that I can select the second paragraph and then call `fill-paragraph` on the region, but I'd like it to work automatically on the current paragraph, not the current comment).

Comment: You mean "entire string"?

Comment: This smells like a lot a bug. If no one comes up with a config
variable for it, I think you should file a bug (even if someone answers with a 
work around).

Comment: @Malabarba That is no bug.  It formats the entire docstring according to the configured docstring style.  That is expected behaviour!  I forgot the name of the corresponding option, which is why I wrote no answer yet, but I wish that people wouldn't shout bug at any behaviour they don't immediately understand…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python Mode provides its own `fill-paragraph-function`, called `python-fill-paragraph`.  This function implements extensive formatting of code beyond just wrapping paragraphs.

#### Change the filling style

Notably, it formats docstrings according to `python-fill-docstring-style`, whose default value is `pep-257`, that is, formatting docstrings according to PEP 257 where the first sentence is one the same line with the opening quotes and a blank line is inserted before the closing quotes.

Your example shows a different docstring style.  Change `python-fill-docstring-style` to `django`

```
(setq python-fill-docstring-style 'django)
```

which is the style used in your example.  Python Mode will still fill the entire docstring, but preserve your style of writing docstrings.

This is the setting I’d recommend.

#### Really fill the paragraph only

Alternatively, you can tell Python Mode to fill only the current paragraph when in a comment, by customizing `python-fill-string-function`.  This is the filling function that Python Mode uses when inside a string.  The following setting makes Python Mode use the default filling behaviour in docstrings:

```
(setq python-fill-string-function (lambda (&optional justify region)
                                    (let ((fill-paragraph-function nil))
                                      (fill-paragraph justify region))))
```

Comment: Until `python-fill-paragraph` is able to preserve at least the proper formatting of bullet points in the docstring, I think this really is an anti-feature.

Comment: @Nikratio You're free to suggest improvements… or implement them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that another solution is to set `python-fill-docstring-style`  to `nil`.

Unfortunately this includes the triple quotes in the reformatting, so when reformatting the last paragraph in a docstring, the triple quotes end up on the same line.